# Cannot marshal 'parameter #': Internal limitation: structure is too complex or too large

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a dll developed in C++. I need to use it with C#.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 205004, Pack = 1)]
    private struct MyList
    {
        public UInt32 count;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
        public myStruct[] info;
    };
```

"myStruct" has of size 2050.
I am calling the dll method as

```
[DllImport("dllName.dll" CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern UInt32 GetMyList(out MyList list);
```

I get an error when I call the dll method. "Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Internal limitation: structure is too complex or too large."

Do any one have a solution by not changing the C++ dll parts?

Comment: If your struct has a size of 2050, why do you say 205004 in c#?

Comment: I have "myStruct" with 2050 size,,and i have a list of such 100 items + "count" with size 4

Comment: Try to use `IntPtr` as parameter, and then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to obtain the structure.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Perhaps this is just a limitation of the runtime.

Comment: If that is your DLL - why not do the proper thing and expose an object model using C++/CLR? AWAY easier and quite alot more performance to deal witth this.

Comment: i can not edit the dll. so i can not edit the paramter to the method "GetMyList(out MyList list)". so is it possible to use     Intptr ?

Comment: @WpfBegnner Yes, you are free to use IntPtr. Check this link: [Cannot marshal parameter :Internal limitation:structure is too complex or too large](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/096e593f-a037-4f1f-9be9-9a56bb41fcd2/cannot-marshal-parameter-internal-limitationstructure-is-too-complex-or-too-large?forum=clr)

Comment: @TomTom You mean C++/CLI

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I consider this vastly superior - good enough I would actualyl write a C++/CLI wrapper around the native dll if I can not change it.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, the structure is too large to be marshalled that way. So you will have to find another approach.

It would make more sense, in my view, to return the structs one at a time. That will avoid you needing to hard code an upper limit of there being no more than 100 structs in the list.

So I would write it like this:

**C++**

```
int GetListCount()
{
    return count;
}

int GetListItem(int index, myStruct* item)
{
    if (index < 0)
        return -1;
    if (index >= count)
        return -1;
    *item = items[index];
    return 0;
}
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport("dllName.dll" CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int GetListCount();

[DllImport("dllName.dll" CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int GetListItem(int index, out myStruct item);

....

int count = GetListCount();
myStruct[] items = new myStruct[count];
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
{
    int retval = GetListItem(out items[index]);
    if (retval != 0)
        // handle error
}
```

If you cannot change the DLL then you are faced with performing the marshalling by hand. It would go like this:

```
[DllImport("dllName.dll" CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern UInt32 GetMyList(IntPtr listPtr);

....

IntPtr listPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(205004); // Argh! Magic constant alert
try
{
    int retval = GetMyList(listPtr);
    // presumably you are expected to do something with retval
    int count = Marshal.ReadInt32(listPtr);
    myStruct[] items = new myStruct[count];
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        IntPtr itemPtr = listPtr + 4 + index*2050; // More magic constants!
        items[index] = (myStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(itemPtr, typeof(myStruct));
    } 
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(listPtr);
}
```

You might prefer to use `Marshal.SizeOf` rather than the magic constants.

Comment: Here you have edited my dll method definition     "private static extern UInt32 GetMyList(out MyList list);" to     "private static extern UInt32 GetMyList(IntPtr listPtr);". I can not change the method declaration also since it need to be changed in the dll coding part.

Comment: If you cannot change your C# code then I'm afraid that you have to give up. Your problem cannot be solved if you are not able to write any code. On the other hand, perhaps you misunderstand me. The change I made to the C# matches the C++ code that you are trying to call. Of course, it would have been nice if you'd included the signature of the C++ code. I've had to infer what it is by assuming that you got the C# translation right.

Comment: Yes..So is it possible to write "private static extern UInt32 GetMyList(out MyList list);"  as  "private static extern UInt32 GetMyList(IntPtr listPtr);"?? If so I can do that change. But I cannot change the C++ coding.

Comment: `out MyList list` marshals as a pointer to the `MyList` struct. Changing to `IntPtr` is needed since you cannot marshal the `MyList` struct. Here we have to allocate the memory ourselves and do all the marshalling. Again, you are asking an interop question but have only shown one side of the interop. Which means that I have had to make assumptions. The general policy is as I have outlined.